# How to run ansible inside virtualenv with terraform local-exec provisioner

Tags: python, docker, ansible, terraform

I believe the title describes everthing. :)
My playbook looks rather simple:

```
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  roles:
    - geerlingguy.docker
```

I run it inside virtualenv. Now I want to launch it using terraform local-exec provisioner for every machine I create. How to do it? Any examples?

Comment: did you tired like `ansible-playbook -i vyos.example.net, -u ansible -k -e ansible_network_os=vyos your_playbook` . local-exec work like bash. if you are able to run the above using bash then it should work in `local-exec`

Comment: How are you managing your virtualenv? Is there a reason you don't want to start the venv in the terminal session you run Terraform in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general answer to how you can run Python software in a virtualenv without first activating that virtualenv in a shell is to explicitly run it via the `python` or `python3` interpreter inside the environment's `bin` directory.

If you run that interpreter then it will automatically be configured to look for dependencies in the virtualenv, rather than system-wide.

For example, if your virtualenv is in `/home/example/foo/env` then you can run its Python interpreter as `/home/example/foo/env/bin/python` (or `python3`).

To do that in Terraform's `local-exec` provisioner, you can do something like the following:

```
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "/home/example/foo/env/bin/python /path/to/ansible ansible-arguments"
  }
```

---

Note that Terraform's provisioners feature is intended as a pragmatic last resort for when other approaches aren't possible. The recommended approach is to build a pre-configured machine image (perhaps using Ansible at build time, or some other configuration management system) so that the machine will launch immediately in the right configuration, without having to separately provision it.

That approach then in turn allows using features such as auto-scaling where new machines might boot up at any time, independent of Terraform.